# How to do "ifconfig lo multicast" using IPROUTE2 / ip command

Tags: iproute

I am trying to figure out how to add the "MULITCAST" parameter to the lo interface using the "ip" command.

I already have a netplan config which adds the multicast route to my lo interface:

```
224.0.0.0/4 dev lo proto static scope link
```

But the lo interface needs to be able to participate in multicast messaging.

example:
Current configuration:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

Desired configuration (note the presence of MULTICAST):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
```

In the ifconfig days, I would issue:  `ifconfig lo mulitcast`

How do I accomplish this with the ip command? (ifconfig is not installed by default on Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `ip link help` and you get the answers :

```
ip l set lo multicast on
```

from `ip-link(8)`:

> ip link set { DEVICE | group GROUP }
>
> ```
>  [ { up | down } ]
>  [ type ETYPE TYPE_ARGS ]
>  [ arp { on | off } ]
>  [ dynamic { on | off } ]
>  [ multicast { on | off } ]
> ```

Comment: bonus question, do you know of a way to accomplish this via netplan yaml file?

Comment: Nope, really sorry.